# Formation mechanism of a non-barred 6-arm spiral galaxy

Tags: dwarf-galaxy

[UGC 12588](https://hla.stsci.edu/hlaview.html#Inventory%7CfilterText%3D%24filterTypes%3D%7Cquery_string=UGC%2012588&posfilename=&poslocalname=&posfilecount=&listdelimiter=whitespace&listformat=degrees&RA=351.176750&Dec=41.346770&Radius=0.014167&inst-control=all&inst=ACS&inst=ACSGrism&inst=WFC3&inst=WFPC2&inst=NICMOS&inst=NICGRISM&inst=COS&inst=WFPC2-PC&inst=STIS&inst=FOS&inst=GHRS&imagetype=best&prop_id=&spectral_elt=&proprietary=both&preview=1&output_size=256&cutout_size=12.8%7Cra=&dec=&sr=&level=&image=&inst=ACS%2CACSGrism%2CWFC3%2CWFPC2%2CNICMOS%2CNICGRISM%2CCOS%2CWFPC2-PC%2CSTIS%2CFOS%2CGHRS&ds=) has an unusual morphology of an old dwarf spheroidal with six very young spiral arms. None of the 24 Simbad references describe its morphology or recent history from the galactic assembly perspective. It lies on the outer edge of the Local Sheet well outside the virial radius of likely interaction candidates. There are several mysteries about it, but the apparent six-arm morphology (if real) is hard to fathom. The HLA proposal was made in Jan 2020 by Brent Tully, but his more recent papers on ADS do not analyse this particular galaxy. The HESTIA project described by [Libeskind 2020](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.04926) simulates surface brightness profiles of dSph galaxies but does not address the tidal and shear stresses that might explain UGC's recent star-forming episode or that 6-arm structure. I'm not keen on guesswork, but that's where I have arrived. Thoughts?